# Keeping certain keys from array of PHP objects

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have an array of PHP objects that I want to go through and keep only a few of the keys. Ideally I want to select those to keep (rather than delete the others) as that list is shorter and more easy for me to follow when reading the script.

```
dump($results);

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#13 (7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "100
    ["rank"]=>
    string(2) "19"
    ["url"]=>
    NULL
    ["score"]=>
    string(2) "14"
    ["forename"]=>
    string(4) "Mary"
    ["surname"]=>
    string(5) "Smith"
    ["sex"]=>
    string(1) "F"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#16 (7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "101"
    ["rank"]=>
    string(2) "20"
    ["url"]=>
    NULL
    ["score"]=>
    string(2) "18"
    ["forename"]=>
    string(4) "Jane"
    ["surname"]=>
    string(5) "Jones"
    ["sex"]=>
    string(1) "F"
  }
}
```

I would like to pick out which keys to keep, for example only pull out the id, forename, and surname so I end up with this:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#13 (3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "100
    ["forename"]=>
    string(4) "Mary"
    ["surname"]=>
    string(5) "Smith"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#16 (3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "101"
    ["forename"]=>
    string(4) "Jane"
    ["surname"]=>
    string(5) "Jones"
  }
}
```

I have tried iterating through the array and using unset, but I couldn't get this to work (and also it wasn't my preferred method for the above reason). Any help?

Comment: Does the `array_intersect_key()` function help you?

Comment: If this is decoded JSON, it may be easier to work with arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally much easier to work with arrays than objects in PHP, so we juggle a bit between the two formats below. A couple of variants:

***Array of objects***

```
    $keep_keys = array_flip(['id', 'forename']);
    
    $data = [
        (object) [ 'id' => '100', 'rank' => '19', 'url' => null, 'score' => '14', 'forename' => 'Mary', 'surname' => 'Smith', 'sex' => 'F' ],
        (object) [ 'id' => '101', 'rank' => '20', 'url' => null, 'score' => '18', 'forename' => 'Jane', 'surname' => 'Jones', 'sex' => 'F' ],
    ];

    $result = array_map(
        function($v) use ($keep_keys) { 
            return (object) array_intersect_key(
                get_object_vars($v), // Simply casting as array, (array) $v, works too
                $keep_keys
            ); 
        }, 
        $data
    );
```

***Array of arrays*** Slightly cleaner, since we don't have to convert the objects to/from arrays:

```
    $keep_keys = array_flip(['id', 'forename']);
    
    $data = [
        [ 'id' => '100', 'rank' => '19', 'url' => null, 'score' => '14', 'forename' => 'Mary', 'surname' => 'Smith', 'sex' => 'F' ],
        [ 'id' => '101', 'rank' => '20', 'url' => null, 'score' => '18', 'forename' => 'Jane', 'surname' => 'Jones', 'sex' => 'F' ],
    ];

    $result = array_map(
        function($v) use ($keep_keys) { 
            return array_intersect_key($v, $keep_keys); 
        }, 
        $data
    );
```

***Using foreach()*** since it was mentioned in the question:

```
    $keep_keys = ['id', 'forename'];
    
    $data = [
        (object) [ 'id' => '100', 'rank' => '19', 'url' => null, 'score' => '14', 'forename' => 'Mary', 'surname' => 'Smith', 'sex' => 'F' ],
        (object) [ 'id' => '101', 'rank' => '20', 'url' => null, 'score' => '18', 'forename' => 'Jane', 'surname' => 'Jones', 'sex' => 'F' ],
    ];

    $all_keys = array_keys(get_object_vars(current($data)));
    $keys_to_remove = array_diff($all_keys, $keep_keys);
    
    foreach($data as $k => $v) {
        foreach($keys_to_remove as $key_to_remove) {
            unset($data[$k]->$key_to_remove);
        }
    }
    
    print_r($data);
```

Note: Of course, this "precalculating the keys to be removed" approach works if all objects in the array look the same, i.e have the same keys. Otherwise the inner foreach() has to be slightly rewritten.